# Set UITableViewCell dynamically based on child UITableView contentSize Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios9

I have an UITableView (aka. ParentTableView) with multiple UITableViewCell's. Each UITableViewCell contains some labels and an UITableView (aka. ChildTableView).

The ChildTableView's rows have different amounts of UITableViewCells.

There is two things I need help to figure out.

#### 1. The height of the ChildTableView should be the height of its contents. So there should be no scroll on this tableview. It's basically just a list.

#### 2. Set the ParentTableView's row height to:  (default height + ChildTableView's calculated height from question 1)

Answer (score 1):

After tableView finishes loading cells ( gets its content ) update the Frame of the TableView with the Content Size.

so after `reloadData`:

```
var bounds = tableView.bounds
bounds.size.height = tableView.contentSize.height
// You can add anything to the height now with bounds.size.height += something
tableView.bounds = bounds
```

You can also explicitly disable the scrolling with `scrollEnabled = false`